# Is there a good PS2 emulator for Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, games, emulation

Is there a good ps2 emulator for ubuntu 13.10.I want a stable ps2 emulator to play on ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use pcsx2, and someone correct me if I'm wrong, I think is the only one availlable.

You can install it from its ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa 

sudo apt-get install  pcsx2-unstable
```

Comment: it's not working.terminal says command not found

Comment: i got pcsx2 but when i try to play it shows a white screen only

Answer (score 4):

You have to use update before you install the software.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install  pcsx2-unstable
```